# Is it possible to add custom SQL-based layers in GeoServer?

Tags: postgis, openlayers-2, geoserver

I would like to add a layer to GeoServer that builds its features from an SQL query executed against a PostGIS database (something like a PostGIS layer in QGIS, but customized with additional SQL query).

Is it possible to have not a whole PostGIS geometries table, but some 'SELECT' from it to be published by GeoServer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that should be possible in Geoserver 2.1 using SQLViews ([Docs](http://gridlock.openplans.org/geoserver/trunk/doc/en/user/data/sqlview.html)).

[image]